# Iphone Rotate video within current frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cgaffinetransform

Hi I am having a video of 
width = 720 
height = 1280

So video is in Portait mode.

I want the video to be rotate by 90 Degree.
BUT want the rotated video inside the same size of video that is 720,1280.
Yes video will be scaled ,
but i need this type of rotation .

Please check Image **before** and **after** :

This is mine code :

```
 CGAffineTransform rotationTransform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90.0));
    CGAffineTransform rotateTranslate =   CGAffineTransformTranslate(rotationTransform,400,320);
    [layerInst setTransform:rotateTranslate atTime:kCMTimeZero];
```

[image: Before video screenshot]
[image: After Video screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use scaling, rotation and translation transform together and concat each transform to original asset transform. Please try below code for your question

```
        // here assetTransform is your AVAssetTrack preferred transform
        CGAffineTransform defaultTransfrom = assetTransform;
        // rotate 90 degree
        CGAffineTransform rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI_2);
        //get scale factor of resized video
        float scaleFactor = videoSize.width/videoSize.height;
        CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
        // get blank Space At Bottom after rotation and scaling
        float blankSpaceAtBottom = (videoSize.height-scaleFactor*videoSize.width);
        //increase y translation according to scaling factor
        float ytranslation = blankSpaceAtBottom/2/scaleFactor;
        CGAffineTransform translationTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(videoSize.height,ytranslation);
        //concat all transform
        CGAffineTransform finalTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(defaultTransfrom,rotateTransform),translationTransform);
       finalTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(finalTransform,scaleTransform);
        //apply final transform to layer instruction
        [layerInstruction setTransform:finalTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
```

Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
fileprivate func rotateTrack(for track: AVAssetTrack, orientation: Orientation) -> CGAffineTransform {
    let size = track.naturalSize
    var transform: CGAffineTransform = .identity
    //get scale factor of resized video
    var scaleFactor: CGFloat = CGFloat(track.naturalSize.width / track.naturalSize.height)
    // get blank Space At Bottom after rotation and scaling
    var blankSpaceAtBottom = 0
    //update x translation according to scaling factor
    var x_translation: CGFloat = 0
    //increase y translation according to scaling factor
    var y_translation: CGFloat = 0

    var defaultRotated = false
    if size.width > size.height {
        defaultRotated = true
        scaleFactor = CGFloat(track.naturalSize.height / track.naturalSize.width)
    }
    let rotate_90: (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat) = (.pi/2, 0, -size.height)
    let rotate_180: (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat) = (.pi, -size.width, -size.height)
    let rotate_270: (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat) = ((3 * .pi) / 2, -size.width, 0)
    let rotate_360: (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat) = (2 * .pi, 0, 0)

    var transformValue: (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat) = (0, 0, 0)
    switch orientation {
        case .upside:
            transformValue = defaultRotated ? rotate_90 : rotate_360
            if defaultRotated {
                blankSpaceAtBottom = Int(track.naturalSize.height - CGFloat(scaleFactor) * track.naturalSize.width)
                x_translation = track.naturalSize.height
                y_translation = CGFloat(blankSpaceAtBottom / 2) / scaleFactor
            }
            scaleFactor = 1
        case .left:
            transformValue = defaultRotated ? rotate_360 : rotate_270
            if defaultRotated {
                scaleFactor = 1
            } else {
                blankSpaceAtBottom = Int(track.naturalSize.height + CGFloat(scaleFactor) * track.naturalSize.width)
                x_translation = 0
                y_translation = CGFloat(blankSpaceAtBottom / 2) / scaleFactor
            }
        case .upsideDown:
            transformValue = defaultRotated ? rotate_270 : rotate_180
            if defaultRotated {
                blankSpaceAtBottom = Int(track.naturalSize.height + CGFloat(scaleFactor) * track.naturalSize.width)
                x_translation = 0
                y_translation = CGFloat(blankSpaceAtBottom / 2) / scaleFactor
            } else {
                x_translation = track.naturalSize.width
                y_translation = track.naturalSize.height
            }
            scaleFactor = 1
        case .right:
            transformValue = defaultRotated ? rotate_180 : rotate_90
            if defaultRotated {
                scaleFactor = 1
                x_translation = track.naturalSize.width
                y_translation = track.naturalSize.height
            } else {
                blankSpaceAtBottom = Int(track.naturalSize.height - CGFloat(scaleFactor) * track.naturalSize.width)
                x_translation = track.naturalSize.height
                y_translation = CGFloat(blankSpaceAtBottom / 2) / scaleFactor
            }
    }
    print(x_translation, y_translation)
    transform = applyTransformValue(transformValue.0, transformValue.1, transformValue.2)

    let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: CGFloat(scaleFactor), y: CGFloat(scaleFactor))
    let translationTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: x_translation, y: CGFloat(y_translation))
    var finalTransform = transform.concatenating(translationTransform)
    finalTransform = finalTransform.concatenating(scaleTransform)
    return finalTransform
}

private func applyTransformValue(_ rotation: CGFloat, _ xValue: CGFloat, _ yValue: CGFloat) -> CGAffineTransform {
    var transform: CGAffineTransform = .identity
    transform = transform.rotated(by: rotation)
    return transform
}
```